# Android how can i get TintContextWrapper context instead of parent class

Tags: android

in my main activity i have simple method which i want to execute that inside adapter, but my `view.getContext()` get wrong class and i cant do that,

**My activity:**

```
public class UnfoldableDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private View listTouchInterceptor;
    private View detailsLayout;
    private UnfoldableView unfoldableView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_unfoldable_details);

        ListView listView = Views.find(this, R.id.list_view);
        listView.setAdapter(new PaintingsAdapter(this));

        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        ...
    }

    public void openDetails(View coverView, Painting painting) {
        ...
    }
}
```

**as you see i set context to adapter by :**

```
ListView listView = Views.find(this, R.id.list_view);
listView.setAdapter(new PaintingsAdapter(this));
```

now in this adapter i must be get correct context from `onClick`:

```
public class PaintingsAdapter extends ItemsAdapter<Painting> implements View.OnClickListener {

    public PaintingsAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setItemsList(Arrays.asList(Painting.getAllPaintings(context.getResources())));
    }

    @Override
    protected View createView(Painting item, int pos, ViewGroup parent, LayoutInflater inflater) {
        ...
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    protected void bindView(Painting item, int pos, View convertView) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Painting item = (Painting) view.getTag(R.id.list_item_image);
        if (view.getContext() instanceof UnfoldableDetailsActivity) {
            ((UnfoldableDetailsActivity) view.getContext()).openDetails(view, item);
        }
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        ...
    }
}
```

`view.getContext()` return `TintContextWrapper`, it must be `UnfoldableDetailsActivity` and its wrong

Comment: You should use listeners for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite it like this:

```
public class PaintingsAdapter extends ItemsAdapter<Painting> implements View.OnClickListener {
    UnfoldableDetailsActivity parentActivity;

    public PaintingsAdapter(UnfoldableDetailsActivity parentActivity) {
        super(context);
        this.parentActivity = parentActivity;
        setItemsList(Arrays.asList(Painting.getAllPaintings(context.getResources())));
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Painting item = (Painting) view.getTag(R.id.list_item_image);
        parentActivity.openDetails(view, item);
    }
}
```

Now you no longer need to cast at all.